# Where can I apt-get install asterisk 11 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, apt, repository, asterisk

If anyone knows of a repo that I can add to my sources.list for asterisk 11 on Ubuntu 16.04 I would be ever grateful. I specifically want to apt install and not compile from source

Answer (score 1):

There is not much packaging made for asterisk. One of the most popular will be the debian/ubuntu official repositories, but there not up-to-date. Those distros freezes a version and apply patches, what makes asterisk version a little tricky (ubuntu 16.04 offers 13.1.0 and debian 9 13.14.1 ). Xivo was building updated packages, but it's for debian. Now wazo is also pushing some packaging, anyway this ones also patches asterisk to adjust with their software...

Comment: Yeah I've noticed, seems there is no a package for version 11 for 16.04. Been hunting for over a week now. Seems the only way around this is to install from source.

Comment: Yes, if you need an up-to-date version, that's the common way ...

Answer (score 0):

I can't find asterisk 11 in the apt repo's, but I could find version 13.1.0 [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/asterisk).

To install it:

1. Make sure that you have the Universe repos enabled

[image: Enable Universe Repository]

2. Install using `sudo apt install asterisk`

Comment: Thanks, was looking for version 11 specifically but it seems there is no package available. Gotta install from source

Answer (score 0):

So it seems even the source compile doesn't work. The chan_sip.so module is not compatible. So, and I stand under correction here, it seems that only asterisk 13 and later is available on Ubuntu 16.04